# java selenium no error appear and element not clicked

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

In selenium webdriver, I have a menu bu it is not "Select menu" so, must be clicked in normal way.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(diagnose_Type));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(diagnose_Type));
```

It is saying no error but i can't complete my script that's meaning that the clicking not actually done.

while the script is running, if i click in the menu, it can select the wanted value an complete the script successfully. please any help.

Comment: We need the full code and the website link to help you.

Comment: Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Once the *WebElement* is returned following the criteria of *elementToBeClickable* you can pass the element while invoking the function `executeScript()` next as follows :

```
WebElement myElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(diagnose_Type));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", myElement);
```